# iOS. BLE. CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse - How to make it work?

Tags: ios

It's my first question here, don't charge me too hard for it.
I would like to get some advise how to sent few bytes from one iOS device to another with CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse.

I did try to sent data with writeValue:forCharacteristic:type: from one iOS device (Central role)
and receive it with peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: on another iOS device (Peripheral role).

I have no problem with type:CBCharacteristicWriteWitResponse, but if I replaced it with type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse peripheral stop receive it. Whats wrong? Do I missing something or WriteWithoutResponse do not supported by CBCentralManagerDelegate?

Here some code:

```
@interface BleCentralDemo : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate> {}
@end

@implementation BleCentralDemo

-(void) writeValue:(int)sUUID characteristicUUID:(int)cUUID p:(CBPeripheral *)p data:(NSData *)data {
[p writeValue:data forCharacteristic:cUUID type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse]; // sent, received
[p writeValue:data forCharacteristic:cUUID type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithOutResponse]; // sent, not received
}
@end

@interface BlePeripheralDemo : NSObject <CBPeripheralManagerDelegate> {}
@end

@implementation BlePeripheralDemo

-(void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests {
 for (CBATTRequest *request in requests){
 NSLog(@"request.value:%@", request.value); 
 [peripheral respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
 }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

i met the same problem today.

you should set your characteristic with CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse properties.(cUUID in your code)

my characteristic is from peripheral device. created like that

```
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:writeableCharacteristicUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite | CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify | CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse value :nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

hope it helps